# Solution of product of congruent equation

Tags: number-theory

If $5x =7\pmod{13}$ and $3y =10\pmod{13}$. What is the value of $k$  in $xy =k\pmod{13}$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $(5x)(3y)=5 \pmod{13}$. As well $5\cdot 3=2\pmod{13}$. So we just need to find the inverse of $2$ under mod 13. This is easily seen to be 7. Hence,

$xy=5\cdot 7\pmod{13}=9\pmod{13}$

Comment: this is not clear to me, why not divide $(5x)(3y)=5\pmod{13}$ by 5 then look for the inverse of 3 instead.

Comment: Sure that works too. I was trying to show it more generally.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\ 13\!:\,\ \color{#C00}7\equiv \color{#0A0}{-6}\ \Rightarrow\ x\cdot y\, \equiv\, \dfrac{\color{#C00}7}{5}\cdot\dfrac{10}3\, \equiv\, \dfrac{\color{#0A0}{-6}}5\cdot \dfrac{10}3\,\equiv\, -2\cdot 2$